# how to sorting according to the value of a field? mongo

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a set of data. When I select the filter conditions, I want to query all the data and put the values that conform to the screening conditions to display in front of the query results.

for example

```
[
    {color: 'blue', name: 'four'},
    {color: 'green', name: 'five'},
    {color: 'red', name: 'one'},
    {color: 'red', name: 'two'},
    {color: 'red', name: 'three'}
]
```

when i choose `color:red`, and limit 4, I want to get the data

```
[
    {color: 'red', name: 'one'},
    {color: 'red', name: 'two'},
    {color: 'red', name: 'three'},
    {color .........}// the fourth of data are not concerned for now
]
```

and when i choose `color:blue`, and limit 4, I want to get the data

```
[
    {color: 'blue', name: 'four'},
    {color  ........},
    {color  ........},
    {color .........}// now just care the first data
]
```

Have some function to achieve this？

My english is so poor, I hope the meaning is clear.

anyway, thanks!

Comment: Hi billy.Lin ; can I confirm that you want to get four records back from the query, even if there's only one record of the colour in your query?

Comment: I just want to advance the results that meet the conditions, and the others don't matter.

Comment: Ah,  you mean you want to query for all the records, but you want to get the records of a specific colour _first_ i.e. at the top of the list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb: Get documents sorted by a dynamic ranking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578496/mongodb-get-documents-sorted-by-a-dynamic-ranking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific example you can write this:

```
db.color.aggregate([{
    $addFields : {
        "rank" : { // add a field called rank to all our documents
            $cond: {
                if: { $eq: [ "$color", "blue" ] }, // if the color value matches "blue"
                then: 0, // then we want items to be on the top
                else: 1 // else we want them to be in the second part
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort : {"rank" : 1} // sort ascending by our newly created "rank" field
}])
```

If you are using an older version of MongoDB (<3.4) that does not support [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) yet you can instead resort to using [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) instead like so:

```
db.color.aggregate([{
    $project : {
        "color": 1, // we want to retain the value of the color field
        "name": 1, // the same goes for the name field
        "rank" : { // add a field called rank to all our documents
            $cond: {
                if: { $eq: [ "$color", "blue" ] }, // if the color value matches "blue"
                then: 0, // then we want items to be on the top
                else: 1 // else we want them to be in the second part
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort : {"rank" : 1} // sort ascending by our newly created "rank" field
}])
```

Comment: thanks!    
ask another question, if I don't have only two fields, and the version is low, how do I write project? each field to 1?  
Is there any easy way to automatically match all the fields in my data table?

Comment: I would need a more concrete case to answer that. Can you provide some sample data and explain what exactly you'd like to get?

Comment: for example, I have some files in this table(name. age, city, phone, address, emall....).  if I use the `$project`, I must write `"name":1,"age":1,"city":1,"phone":1, "address":1,"email": 1.......    "rank": .`?

Comment: Yes, that's a bit annoying. But starting with MongoDB 3.4 you can use $addFields instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) function, then you can use the [`sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) function.
If the aggregation framework, then the pipeline [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) stage.

Comment: The official document is a bit blurred. Can you help write a code based on my question?